# Element type is invalid error with youtube component in React-Native

Tags: youtube, react-native

I'm trying to use youtube component in my react-native app. But it keeps giving me an error "element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object. Check the render method of xx"

I installed react-native-youtube and my package.json seems to be ok.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "15.2.1",
    "react-native": "0.30.0",
    "react-native-tabbar-navigator": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-youtube": "^0.7.2"
  }
}
```

And my Main.js code looks like the below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image
} from 'react-native';


var YouTube = require('react-native-youtube');



Class Main extends Component {


render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <YouTube
        ref="youtubePlayer"
        videoId="KVZ-P-ZI6W4" 
        play={true}           
        hidden={false}        
        playsInline={true}    
        loop={false}          
        onReady={(e)=>{this.setState({isReady: true})}}
        onChangeState={(e)=>{this.setState({status: e.state})}}
        onChangeQuality={(e)=>{this.setState({quality: e.quality})}}
        onError={(e)=>{this.setState({error: e.error})}}
        onProgress={(e)=>{this.setState({currentTime: e.currentTime, duration: e.duration})}}

        style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300, backgroundColor: 'black', marginVertical: 10}}/>

</View>

    );
    }

    }
```

I really have no idea why this error happens. Please share any ideas you have!! (:
Best

Answer (score 0):

Use `import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';` instead of `var YouTube = require('react-native-youtube');`

Also, you have `Class` in your code starting with uppercase instead of `class`

Comment: Thanks! It seems the error is gone. However, I now see a blank component. If I double click this blank component, then it shrinks with a black-colored background, which seems to be a square. Do you have any idea why the content is not displayed? (:

Comment: Did you properly install ios part of the module? i.e. run `react-native link` and copy html asset into xcode project

Comment: Hi Konstantin! As you said, I properly located the html file to xcode project. I was not sure where to put and happened to mistakenly put into the wrong directory. Thanks! It works now! (: